# Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn't compile in javac

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

> *Note*: This is a spin-off from [Comparable and Comparator contract with regards to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858628/comparable-and-comparator-contract-with-regards-to-null)

This code compiles and runs fine in Eclipse (`20090920-1017`)

```
import java.util.*;
public class SortNull {
   static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
   Comparator<T> nullComparableComparator() {
      return new Comparator<T>() {
         @Override public int compare(T el1, T el2) {
         return
            el1 == null ? -1 :
            el2 == null ? +1 :
            el1.compareTo(el2);
         }
      };
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(
         Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1, null, null, 0)
      );
      Comparator<Integer> numbersComp = nullComparableComparator();
      Collections.sort(numbers, numbersComp);
      System.out.println(numbers);
      // "[null, null, 0, 1, 2, 3]"

      List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(
         Arrays.asList("Bob", null, "Alice", "Carol")
      );
      Comparator<String> namesComp = nullComparableComparator();
      Collections.sort(names, namesComp);
      System.out.println(names);
      // "[null, Alice, Bob, Carol]"
   }
}
```

And yet it doesn't compile on `javac 1.6.0_17`. This is the error message:

```
SortNull.java:17: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist
 so that java.util.Comparator<T> conforms
 to java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Integer>
found   : <T>java.util.Comparator<T>
required: java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Integer>
     Comparator<Integer> numbersComp = nullComparableComparator();

SortNull.java:25: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist
 so that java.util.Comparator<T> conforms
 to java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String>
found   : <T>java.util.Comparator<T>
required: java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String>
     Comparator<String> namesComp = nullComparableComparator();

2 errors
```

Can someone explain why the discrepancy? Is this a bug? If so, who has the bug?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug: [Bug ID 6468354](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6468354). Here's an extract of relevance:

> This problem is caused by the fact that sometimes javac's implementation of [JLS3 15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.8) ignores recursive bounds, sometimes not (as in this case). When recursive bounds contains wildcards, such bounds are included when computing uninferred type variables. This makes subsequent subtyping `test (Integer <: Comparable<? super T>` where `T` is a type-variable to be inferred).
>
> **Will be fixed after [6369605](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6369605)**

Occured to me on WinXP with 1.6.0_13 as well. Ah well, I'll just stick using Eclipse :)

Comment: No, [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22incompatible+types%3B+no+instance%28s%29+of+type+variable%28s%29%22+site%3Abugs.sun.com) is awesome.

Comment: LOL yes, I know how to use Google, I was just so caught up in the excitement and just post the question right away =) I hope that's not "bad question behavior" that you're encouraging by answering it =)

Answer (score 16):

You can get around this by explicitly specifying the generic class:

```
Comparator<String> namesComp = Stack.<String>nullComparableComparator();
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and upgraded from jdk1.6.0_16 to jdk1.6.0_23 and it went away without any code changes.

Comment: I have 1.6.0_24 Java compiler, and unfortunately this issue came up. Sun's bug database specifies fix release to 7(b109) (I assume that it's JDK7), so probably you just had a luck ;) After specifying type explicitly, as Michael suggests, everything works fine.