# Generic static factory method problem

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, netbeans

I have class like following:

```
public class Tree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
  // private data omitted
  private Tree() {} // non parametric private constructor, not exposed
  // static factory method
  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Tree<T> newInstance() { 
    return new Tree<T>(); 
  }
}
```

Now from another class I try this:

```
public class TestClass {
  public void test() {
    Tree<Integer> tree = Tree.newInstance(); // fail
  }
}
```

but when I use public constructor, following code works just fine

```
public void test() {
  Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<Integer>(); 
}
```

What might I have done wrong?

Here is error message:

```
Incompatibile types:
required: structures.trees.Tree<java.lang.Integer>
found: <T>structures.trees.Tree<T>
```

Now the **weirdness**: You can try this for yourself. This code does work with my Eclipse 3.6 Helios, but it doesn't with my NetBeans 6.9.1. I can't believe it's IDE's issue (I am even using same JDK for both) ... An ideas? :O

Comment: Duplicate of [Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn't compile in javac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858799/generics-compiles-and-runs-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-compile-in-javac). It's a [bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6468354) in javac.

Comment: By the way, you forgot `static` in the `newInstance()` method.

Comment: Can't you just write the method as `public static Tree<T> newInstance()` and it will automatically fill in the `T` from the class declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BalusC comment - javac bug.

Solved by explicit typing:

```
Tree<Integer> tree = Tree.<Integer>newInstance();
```