# How to resolve generic recursive bound problems?

Tags: java, generics

I have some problems to compile my codes.

```
$ mvn clean compile
```

notify me like this kinds of errors.

```
[58,30] type parameters of <D,K>D cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable D with upper bounds DS,
```

Maybe this problem is caused by `recursive bounds of generic types`. Right?

References: 
[Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn't compile in javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858799/generics-compiles-and-runs-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-compile-in-javac)

How could I fix this one?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <D extends DataStore<K, T>, K, T extends Persistent> D createDataStore(Class<T> persistent, Properties properties) throws IOException {
    try {
        return (D) (new HBaseStore<K, T>());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot initialize a datastore", e);
    }
}

public static <DS extends DataStore<U, P>, U, P extends Persistent> DS createDataStore(Class<P> persistent) throws IOException {
    return createDataStore(persistent, null); // ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that type `D` exists as a generic parameter only. For example `T` can be resolved from method argument `Class<T> persistent`. You can solve this problem if you change signature of the method to something like:

```
public static <D extends DataStore<K, T>, K, T extends Persistent> D createDataStore(Class<T> persistent, Class<D> dataStoreType, Properties properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

When types of arguments do not provide enough info for the compiler to infer generic type parameters, you can explicitly give the types parameters. For non-static methods you would say `this.<list of type parameters>methodName(...)`. For an static method like this, you put class name instead of `this`

```
public static <DS extends DataStore<U, P>, U, P extends Persistent> DS createDataStore(Class<P> persistent) throws IOException {
    return NameOfThisClass.<DS, U, P>createDataStore(persistent, null); // ERROR
}
```