# Java CRTP and Wildcards: Code compiles in Eclipse but not `javac`

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, javac

Sorry for the vague title. I have this piece of code which compiles on Eclipse Juno (4.2) but not javac (1.7.0_09):

```
package test;

public final class Test {
    public static class N<T extends N<T>> {}

    public static class R<T extends N<T>> {
        public T o;
    }

    public <T extends N<T>> void p(final T n) {}

    public void v(final R<?> r) {
        p(r.o);       // <-- javac fails on this line
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Test.java:13: error: method p in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
        p(r.o);
        ^
  required: T
  found: N<CAP#1>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: N<CAP#1>
    bound(s): N<N<CAP#1>>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends N<T> declared in method <T>p(T)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends N<CAP#1> from capture of ?
1 error
```

So the questions are:

1. Is this a `javac` bug or Eclipse bug?
2. Is there any way to make this compile on `javac`, without changing the signature of the `v` method (i.e. keep the wildcard)?

   I know changing it to `<T extends N<T>> void v(final R<T> r)` does make it compile, but I would like to know if there's way to avoid this first. Also, the method `p` cannot be changed to `<T extends N<?>> void p(final T n)` because the content have types which requires the exact constraint `T extends N<T>`.

Comment: @Nambari: It is also 1.7. Also, Eclipse does not use `javac` to compile the code, but its own compiler.

Comment: It compiles in my eclipse with java 6 what java version are you using?

Comment: @AmitD: Yes it works on Eclipse on both 1.6 and 1.7, but it won't compile with OpenJDK 6 and 7's javac, nor [Sun's JDK 6 on ideone](http://ideone.com/Z03W7V).

Comment: @Nambari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make this compile using javac unless you make the change as you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wildcards are limited in that they break recursive expressions like `T extends X<T>` that type parameters allow. We know what you're trying to do is safe based on the following:

1. `r.o` is of type `T` (declared by `R`), which is or extends `N<T>`.
2. The method `p` takes an argument of type `T` (declared by `p`), which also is or extends `N<T>`.
3. So even though `r` is typed as `R<?>`, a call `p(r.o)` should theoretically be legal.

This is possibly the reasoning of the eclipse compiler (known to make correct allowances for certain nuances of generics where [javac doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858800/697449)).

Assuming you want to compile with javac and can't change the signature of `v` like you mentioned, the best you can do is resort to using a raw type, which "opts out" of generic type checking:

```
public void v(final R<?> r) {
    //necessary to placate javac - this is okay because [insert above reasoning]
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    N nRaw = r.o;
    p(nRaw);
}
```