# java reference "this" from anonymous method

Tags: java, anonymous-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)

My class (let's call it `MyClass`) has `m_listener` member that is used for notification purposes. There's no problem to use it from within an anonymous method:

```
private void myMethod(SomeObj myObj)
{
    ...
    myObj.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            m_listener.myOnClick(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

In the code `this` refers to the anonymous `OnTouchListener` instance. What should I write instead of `this` to refer to `MyClass` instance (just like `m_listener` refers to `MyClass.m_listener`, not to the `OnTouchListener.m_listener`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MyClass.this` to refer to the outer `MyClass` instance.

Comment: It saddens me that I get more rep from trivial answers like this than more interesting ones like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13214630/697449).

Answer (score 1):

To refer to MyClass instance use `MyClass.this`