# Java generic code builds in eclipse, but not in mvn (same VM version)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, generics

Can anyone help me to find what's wrong with this piece of code run in **jdk1.6.0_45**?

```
public class App {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        SortComparator<String, Integer> a = build();
    }

    private static <T, O extends Comparable<O>> SortComparator<T, O> build() {
        return null;
    }

    public class SortComparator<T, O extends Comparable<O>> implement Comparator<T> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a pure Java language question. Why it does not compile? Why it does in Eclipse?

- If I change `SortComparator<String, Integer>` to `Map<String, Integer>` it compiles.
- If I add the parameter *Class< O> arg* as an argument of *build* it compiles.
- If I add *App. build()* to the call it compiles.

**Console output**:

```
incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,O exist so that build<T,O> conforms to SortComparator<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>
```

**Versions**

- Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
- Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
- Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
- OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Comment: What error do you get from the compiler?

Comment: The console output is: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,O exist so that build<T,O> conforms to SortComparator<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>

Comment: Note that Eclipse uses its own compiler, which might explain the difference in behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics compiles and runs in Eclipse, but doesn't compile in javac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858799/generics-compiles-and-runs-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-compile-in-javac)

Comment: Your example is incomplete, this code compiles well in Java 1.6, I just added dummy implementation of Comparator#compare method in SortComparator

Comment: @hoaz I have updated the code, I removed the parameter, now it fails (sorry for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the return type of `SortComparator` is not a tuple (or Map.Entry).

```
// Only takes one argument...
private <O extends Comparable<O>> SortComparator<O> build(final Class<O> clazz) {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following example and it compile fine in both Eclipse and from command line:

```
public class Test {

    public static class SortComparator<T, O extends Comparable<O>> implements Comparator<T> {
        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static <T, O extends Comparable<O>> SortComparator<T, O> build(
            final Class<O> clazz) {
        // you can return null here too
        return new SortComparator<T, O>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortComparator<String, Integer> a = build(Integer.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you have static import of `build` method in your class and it makes your App.build() invisible