# Ambiguous varargs method call compilation error

Tags: java, variadic-functions

```
method(1);  // This works -

void method(int... x) { }
void method(int x) { }  // - this method is called
```

If I add a varargs parameter to the second method, I get a "reference to method is ambiguous" compilation error:

```
method(1);  // This now fails

void method(int... x) { }
void method(int x, String... y) { }  // adding String... y causes a problem.
```

As the String... y argument(s) can be left "blank", why doesn't Java still pick that method?  Thanks, and apologies if there is a closely matching explanation on SO; I did look for one.

Comment: Could you share the exact compiler error you're getting?

Comment: @Alexis Leclerc   ..\src\pkgs\main\Main.java:1278: error: reference to method is ambiguous, both method method(int...) in Main and method method(int,String...) in Main match
                method(1);

Comment: I copy pasted your methods and it compiled just fine

Comment: @Gladhus Cannot be. Did you copy the second one?

Comment: Yup, If I comment out the first method, it calls the second one, and if I leave both of them uncommented, it calls the first one... Weird weird weird

Comment: On my side compiles fine too, please add more details about compiler and compiler settings

Comment: [Guys.. This **DOESN'T** compile...](https://ideone.com/UyjYuF)

Comment: Hey, don't blame me, I swear it does. I do understand why it **shouldn't** though

Comment: @Gladhus I'm not blaming you, just make sure you're running the case that *should* cause the compilation error.

Comment: It compiles for me too, but I'm under Java 6 with Eclipse, if that makes any difference...

Comment: @DayaMoon, I would be very happy too.  I'm a relative Java noob.  Please can you tell me how to get this info?  Some basic info for you: if I type javac -version at the Windows command prompt, I see 1.7.0_40.  Also, I am using Notepad to write my programs - no IDE.

Comment: Only one explanation here... My java compiler **reads my mind**

Comment: @Gladhus:  There has to be something... from IDE it compiles/runs, but from  shell it does not compile.

Comment: It seems there is a difference between IDE and JDK compiler... See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858799/generics-compiles-and-runs-in-eclipse-but-doesnt-compile-in-javac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler always makes the choice to use the *most* specific method.

In the first case, because the *number* of the arguments *exactly* matches `void method(int x)`, it is the one that's being called.

In the second case, the number of the arguments don't match any case, and it can be called from both methods, resulting the ambiguity.

Check the [**JLS - 15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments can be 0 or many. which makes

`void method(int x, String... y){ }` is similar to `void method(int x){}`

And the

`void method(int... x){}` is also similar to `void method(int x){}`

If you call method(1), the compiler will find two applicable method to this call and raises and exception.