# How to sort Map in Java

Tags: java

i want to sort map according to its key value
plz see code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SortedMap map = new TreeMap();

    // Add some elements:
    map.put("2", "Two");
    map.put("1", "One");
    map.put("5", "Five");
    map.put("4", "Four");
    map.put("3", "Three");
    map.put("10", "Ten");
    map.put("12", "Twelve");
    map.put("7", "Seven");
    map.put("9", "Nine");

    Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object key = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("key : " + key + " value :" + map.get(key));
    }


}

 Result Should come below

key : 1 value :One
key : 2 value :Two
key : 3 value :Three
key : 4 value :Four
key : 5 value :Five
key : 7 value :Seven
key : 9 value :Nine
key : 10 value :Ten
key : 12 value :Twelve
```

Comment: Does the key have to be a String? If not define the Map as follows:

`SortedMap map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>()`

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/UseGenericTreeMaptostoreIntegeraskeyandStringasvalue.htm

Answer (score 10):

I guess your problem is that keys "10" and "12" come before "2" (btw you **should** be more specific about your problem next time). This is simply due to the way strings are sorted.

If you want the keys to be sorted according to their integer values, you have the following options:

- use `Integer` keys instead of `String`s
- insert leading zeroes into the string keys to make them equally long, i.e. `"01"` instead of `"1"` etc.
- use a special `Comparator` which sorts according to your wish.

Answer (score 4):

Implement a custom Comparator and create the TreeMap with this little helper. The Comparator provides the order ("1" < "2" < "3" < ... < "10" < ... < "100").

Answer (score 4):

A `TreeMap` is a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), which sorts by keys. The way you were using it, you have `String` keys, and its natural ordering is lexicographical, where `"11" < "2"`.

Here's an illustration using `List` to simplify:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("2", "1", "11", "b", "a", "aa")
);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list); // prints "[1, 11, 2, a, aa, b]"
```

Note the analogy between `1, 11, 2` and `a, aa, b`. This is precisely what lexicographical ordering mandates. In a dictionary, you expect `aa` to appear before `b`. Similary, in this ordering, you expect `11` to appear before `2`.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

---

If you need to compare them as `Integer`, use a custom `Comparator<String>`:

```
Comparator<String> stringAsInteger = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));
    }
};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("2", "1", "10", "007")
);
Collections.sort(list, stringAsInteger);
System.out.println(list); // prints "[1, 2, 007, 10]"

SortedMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(stringAsInteger);
map.put("2", "Two");
map.put("1", "One");
map.put("10", "Ten");
map.put("12", "Twelve");
map.put("7", "Seven");
System.out.println(map); // prints "{1=One, 2=Two, 7=Seven, 10=Ten, 12=Twelve}"
```

#### API links

- [`java.util.Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) -- there are 2 overloads

#### Related questions

On `Comparator` and `Comparable`

- [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator)
- [difference between compare() and compareTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/difference-between-compare-and-compareto)
- [Comparable and Comparator contract with regards to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858628/comparable-and-comparator-contract-with-regards-to-null)
- [Why does the Java Collections Framework offer two different ways to sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892947/why-does-the-java-collections-framework-offer-two-different-ways-to-sort/)

On sorting `Map` by values

- [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)
- [How to sort a Map on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

---

#### On raw types

*Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 23: Don't use raw types in new code*

#### Related questions

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Near the top you show this style of syntax: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c") );`  I've also used this syntax `List<String> list = Arrays.asList( new String[]{"a", "b", "c"} );`  Curious if you had any comments for pro/con on either way?  I had came to my syntax by trial and error, so not attached to it.