# Sorting ArrayList of Objects by Object attribute

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist

I am having an Arraylist of Objects. Those object have an attribute or datatype - 'String'. 
I need to sort the Arraylist by that string. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to write a [`Comparator<MyObject>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your `List`.

Or else, your `MyObject` can also [`implements Comparable<MyObject>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), defining a *natural ordering* that compares on your specific attribute, and then use [`Collections.sort(List<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) instead.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Object Ordering](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

#### Related questions

On sorting `List` on various criteria:

- [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts)

On `Comparator` and `Comparable`

- [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator)
- [difference between compare() and compareTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/difference-between-compare-and-compareto)
- [Comparable and Comparator contract with regards to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858628/comparable-and-comparator-contract-with-regards-to-null)
- [Why does the Java Collections Framework offer two different ways to sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892947/why-does-the-java-collections-framework-offer-two-different-ways-to-sort/)

Comment: Thanks! :) Can you elaborate more about the use of comparator and how it will return me sorted objects according to string. Note that I need to sort them in alphabetical order of String.

Comment: Oh. Got the idea about comparator. But I cant implement this interface on the Object because of some other issues. So I need to make Comparator object.

Comment: @Vishal: look at the linked question (Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts). It has the examples you're looking for and more. Also, _Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 12: Consider implementing Comparable_

Answer (score 7):

Another good way of doing this that is a bit more flexible if there is more than one property of an object that you may wish to sort by is to use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Ordering](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class with its `onResultOf(Function)` option. This is ideally suited for sorting by properties since a [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) can be used to retrieve and return a specific property of an object.
For a simple example, imagine a class `Person` with `String getFirstName()` and `String getLastName()` methods.

```
List<Person> people = ...;
Collections.sort(people, Ordering.natural().onResultOf(
    new Function<Person, String>() {
      public String apply(Person from) {
        return from.getFirstName();
      }
    }));
```

The above will sort the list by first name.

To make it read nicer, you may want to define the functions you might want to use as `public static final` fields on the `Person` class. Then you could sort by last name like this:

```
Collections.sort(people, Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Person.GET_LAST_NAME));
```

As a fun aside note, this will all be a lot easier in Java 8 with lambda expressions and method references. You'll be able to write something like this without having to define any clumsy anonymous inner classes or static final fields:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
...

people.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName));
```

Comment: You're right. It should have been much easier in Java 8 with lambda expression. Unfortunately Sun and Oracle missed again the opportunity to add some high-level methods like sortBy to collections and arrays. So a trivial Scala line of code ("people.sortBy(_.lastName)") is still translated into a four times longer Java line of code. That's sad. But anyway, thanks for this Guava shortcut with the Ordering class. It's still useful in Java 8.

Comment: @StefanEndrullis: With one static import, the same thing in Java 8 looks like this: `people.sort(comparing(Person::lastName))`. Seems like you're underselling it a bit.

Comment: OK, your last edit by statically importing `comparing` makes it also quite short and readable. Thanks for the tip.