# Sorting Arraylist of Custom object by creation date

Tags: java, datetime, sorting, arraylist, custom-object

I have a custom object whose structure is

```
public String name;
public int type;
public String createdOn;
```

`createdOn` is date and its format is : `2011-12-16T23:27:27+0000`

I have stored multiple objects of this type in `ArrayList` and now I want to sort them according to there creation date and time.

I have tried using `Collections.sort(....)` , but  no suitable result.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and explain us why you store dates as Strings rather than storing them as Dates.

Comment: can you show what you've tried already..

Comment: use Dates as Dates rather then String or better yet, modify your object and add another value (if possible derived from data/time) on which you can perform sorting

Comment: pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342517/sorting-arraylist-of-objects-by-object-attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing some R&D after getting answers, I solved the sorting thing, here is the code to sort array list by date.

```
Collections.sort(arrlst,new Comparator<T>() {

                    public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) {

                        try {
                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatlhs = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
                            Date convertedDatelhs = dateFormatlhs.parse(lhs.feedCreatedTime);
                            Calendar calendarlhs = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendarlhs.setTime(convertedDatelhs);

                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatrhs = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
                            Date convertedDaterhs = dateFormatrhs.parse(rhs.feedCreatedTime);
                            Calendar calendarrhs = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendarrhs.setTime(convertedDaterhs);

                            if(calendarlhs.getTimeInMillis() > calendarrhs.getTimeInMillis())
                            {   


                                return -1;
                            }
                            else
                            {


                                return 1;

                            }
                        } catch (ParseException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        return 0;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and implement a comparator like

```
Comparator c = new Comparator<YourObject>() {
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
       return o1.createdOn.compareTo(o2.createdOn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own Custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/UseCollectionssorttosortcustomclassanduserdefinedComparator.htm)). You will most likely have to parse the strings back to dates. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java) previous SO post to see how you can compare dates.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your custom object.

Implementing a Comparable you define a natural ordering for your objects. In the [Comparable.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method you have to compare the current object with another one and return

- a negative integer if the current object is "less than" the other one;
- zero if the current object is "equal" to the other one;
- a positive integer if the current object is "greater than" the other one.

An example:

```
public class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CustomObject otherOne) {
        // Compare the current object with the otherOne and return an
        // appropriate integer
        return 0;
    }

}

// To sort

Collections.sort(listOfCustomObjects);
```

From the other side, implementing a Comparator you can specify an ordering criteria outside the code of the custom Object. Using the appropriate [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method, you can specify the order for the objects in a collection. The [Comparator.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method follows the same rules explained above.

An example:

```
public class CustomObjectComparator implements Comparator<CustomObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(CustomObject a, CustomObject b) {
        // Compare a with b and return an appropriate integer
        return 0;
    }

}

// To sort

Collections.sort(list, new CustomObjectComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Custom object, you need a custom Comparator or you need to make the class comparable.

You could convert the date string each time, or you could just compare strings (provided the time zone doesn't change)

As has been suggested, storing dates as a Date or a long is likely to be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing your custom `Comparator`?

```
new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
    public int compare(CustomObject o1, CustomObject o2) {
       //compare by date 
       return <-1 or 0 or 1>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement interface `Comparable`. In this case you can implement `compareTo()` method according to your needs.

Alternatively you can implement your custom comparator:

```
class MyCreationDateComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        // implement your logic here.
    } 
}
```

Now use version of `Collections.sort()`that accepts custom comparator. If your comparator is simple you can use anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342517/sorting-arraylist-of-objects-by-object-attribute), just use a method from the Date class to compare dates