# How to sort by String value of object in Java

Tags: java, comparison

I have Java bean class and I want to sort list of these beans by one bean attribute that is of String type. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342517/sorting-arraylist-of-objects-by-object-attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either make the type itself implement [`Comparable<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), implementing the `compareTo` method by comparing the two strings, or implement a [`Comparator<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which again compares by the strings.

With the first approach, you'd then just be able to use `Collections.sort()` directly; with the second you'd use `Collections.sort(collection, new FooComparator());`

For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public String getBar() {
        ...
    }
}

public class FooComparatorByBar implements Comparator<Foo> {
    public int compare(Foo x, Foo y) {
        // TODO: Handle null values of x, y, x.getBar() and y.getBar(),
        // and consider non-ordinal orderings.
        return x.getBar().compareTo(y.getBar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Should that be Comparator rather than Comparer?

Answer (score 1):

By using a custom Comparator?

```
import java.util.*;

class Bean {
    public final String name;
    public final int value;

    public Bean(final String name, final int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " = " + value;
    }
}

public class SortByProp {
    private static List<Bean> initBeans() {
        return new ArrayList<Bean>(Arrays.asList(
            new Bean("C", 1),
            new Bean("B", 2),
            new Bean("A", 3)
        ));
    }

    private static void sortBeans(List<Bean> beans) {
        Collections.sort(beans, new Comparator<Bean>() {
            public int compare(Bean lhs, Bean rhs){ 
                return lhs.name.compareTo(rhs.name);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bean> beans = initBeans();
        sortBeans(beans);
        System.out.println(beans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained), it's just

```
Collections.sort(list, Ordering.natural().compose(Functions.toStringFunction()));
```