# how to do sort an Array List in ascending order according to 2nd attribute but ascending should be depend on occurrences?

Tags: java

```
class helper {
  public int a;
  public int b;
}
```

And in main function

```
List<helper> helpers  = new ArrayList<helper>();
```

Suppose at any instant helpers content is

```
         1     4
         1     5
         1     6
         2     4
         3     4
         2     5
```

I want the Output in sorted way like below

```
         1     6
         1     5
         2     5
         1     4
         2     4
         3     4
```

This is not the Sort in descending order of 2nd column but in ascending order of the occurrences in the 2nd Column. Like 6 occurs once in 2nd column and is less than others occurrences so comes 1st. and then 5 occurs two times so it is also before than 4

Comment: Hope this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342517/sorting-arraylist-of-objects-by-object-attribute

Comment: do you have any limits for a , b ? like max / min

Comment: No Sir, Actually not but a is not equal to b. but we can assume a & b<1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Helper {

    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Helper(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Helper> helpers = new ArrayList<Helper>();

        helpers.add(new Helper(1, 4));
        helpers.add(new Helper(1, 5));
        helpers.add(new Helper(1, 6));
        helpers.add(new Helper(2, 4));
        helpers.add(new Helper(3, 4));
        helpers.add(new Helper(2, 4));

        System.out.println(helpers);

        Collections.sort(helpers,new Comparator<Helper>(){
            public int compare(Helper h1, Helper h2){
              return (countOccurance(h1.b) > countOccurance(h2.b)) ? 1 : -1;
            }

            private int countOccurance(int b) {
                int count = 0;

                for(Helper h : helpers){
                    if(h.b == b) count++;
                }

                return count;
            }});

        System.out.println(helpers);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Helper [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store your column two numbers in a HashMap, where the key is the column two number and the value is the frequency at which you've seen that number.

Then, for sorting, use Collections.sort, providing a comparator.

In the compareTo() implementation, look up each number's frequency and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have set data and Display records

```
        List<helper> helpers = new ArrayList<helper>();
        helpers.add(new helper(1, 4));
    helpers.add(new helper(1, 5));
    helpers.add(new helper(1, 6));
    helpers.add(new helper(2, 4));
    helpers.add(new helper(3, 4));
    helpers.add(new helper(2, 5));

         [1 4, 1 5, 1 6, 2 4, 3 4, 2 5]
```

Create a `HashMap` to hold `Integer,List<helpers>`

```
Map<Integer, List<helper>> holder = new HashMap<Integer, List<helper>>();
```

Load the HashMap based on b values.

```
for (int i=0;i<helpers.size();i++){
        List<helper> tmp = holder.get(helpers.get(i).getB());
        if (tmp == null){
            tmp = new ArrayList<helper>();
        }
        tmp.add(helpers.get(i));
        holder.put(helpers.get(i).getB(), tmp);
    }
```

Display Map

```
{4=[1 4, 2 4, 3 4], 5=[1 5, 2 5], 6=[1 6]}
```

Now start ascending order of Map values based on size of elements

```
List mapValues = new ArrayList(holder.values());
        Collections.sort(mapValues,new helperComparator());
System.out.println(mapValues);
```

and the comparator

```
class helperComparator implements Comparator<List<helper>>{

    @Override
    public int compare(List<helper> o1, List<helper> o2) {
        return o1.size() > o2.size() ? 1 : -1;
    }

}
```

And the final result

[[1 6], [1 5, 2 5], [1 4, 2 4, 3 4]]

Note the result `mapValues` is a `List<List<helpers>>` . I hope u can flat the helpers.